# Jquery UI Autocomplete - Select Value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a bit of PHP and JQuery which creates the Autocomplete form:

```
<?
mysql_select_db($database_database_connection, $database_connection);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Device_tbl";
$result=mysql_query($query, $database_connection) or die(mysql_error());
$findrow = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $manufac = $row['Manufacturer'];
    $mod = $row['Model'];
    $string = $manufac.' '.$mod;
    $findrow[] = $string;
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_input").watermark("Begin Typing to Search");

  var availableTags = <? echo json_encode($findrow);?>;
  $( "#search_input" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
            });


    $("#search_input").bind("autocompleteselect", function() {
        var search_input = $(this).val();
        if (search_input =='') search_input ='*';
        var dataString = 'keyword='+search_input;

        if (search_input.length > 2 || search_input=='*') {
           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "core/functions/searchdata.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(server_response) {
                    $('#searchresultdata').empty();
                    $('#searchresultdata').append(server_response);
                    $('span#category_title').html(search_input);
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
    $("#search_input").trigger('keyup');
});
</script>
```

**searchdata.php**

```
mysql_select_db($database_database_connection, $database_connection);
$query = "SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model FROM Device_tbl WHERE Manufacturer LIKE '%$keyword%' OR Model LIKE '%$keyword%'";
if ($keyword=='*') $query = "SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model FROM Device_tbl";
$result=mysql_query($query, $database_connection) or die(mysql_error());

if($result){
    if(mysql_affected_rows($database_connection)!=0){
          while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
?>
     <div class="hold-cont">
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="image-hold" >
                <img class="image-icon" src="<? echo $deviceimg.($row->Image); ?>"/>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-name devicename-txt"><? echo($row->Manufacturer. ' ' .$row->Model);  ?></div>
    </div>
     <?
    }
    }else {
        echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';
    }

}
else {
    echo 'Parameter Missing';
```

The autocomplete part works fine, however what I can't get to work is running the .ajax on the selected value. If, for example I started typing "Apple iMac" and only got as far as "Ap".  The suggestion would be Apple iMac, however when I click on the suggestion, it runs the query on "Ap" - ie, its only running the query on what is typed, not what is clicked.

Any ideas how I can make this work when the user either clicks a suggestion OR hits enter?

Comment: can you provide the script of `searchdata.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "#search_input" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        sendSelected(ui.item.value);
        }
    });

function sendSelected(_val){
    var search_input = _val;
    if (search_input =='') search_input ='*';
    var dataString = 'keyword='+search_input;

    if (search_input.length > 2 || search_input=='*') {
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "core/functions/searchdata.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(server_response) {
                $('#searchresultdata').empty();
                $('#searchresultdata').append(server_response);
                $('span#category_title').html(search_input);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

searchdata.php:

```
$splitKeyword = explode(" ", $keyword);
if(sizeof($splitKeyword)==3){
    $splitKeyword[1] = $splitKeyword[1]." ".$splitKeyword[2];
 }
$query = "SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model FROM Device_tbl WHERE Manufacturer LIKE '%".$splitKeyword[0]."%' OR Model LIKE '%".$splitKeyword[1]."%'";
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks.  However, my SQL clearly doesn't work.  Its looking for LIKE Honda Civic in the Manufacturer OR the Model.  And since it cant find anything like that, it returns nothing.  Even though the database as the Manufacturer Honda and the model for it, Civic :/

Comment: try this : `... LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR...`

Comment: Same problem.  I believe its because the ui.item.value is a combination of the Manufacturer and Model fields in the database.  However, I thought that since I'm doing a LIKE query, it would still find it. 'Honda Civic' is LIKE the Manufacturer 'Honda'...right?

Comment: @K20GH if you pass `Honda Civic` `LIKE` Will only look for char after and before `Honda Civic`, but you split them

Comment: @K20GH `$splitKeyword[0]` will return `Honda`, `$splitKeyword[1]` will return `Civic`

Comment: Cheers.  I see how that works, however is there no simple way for it to return only what is selected from the dropdown list? For instance, if I had every 'Sony Ericsson' phone ever made.  Selecting any 'Sony Ericsson' phone from the list would bring back every single Sony Ericsson phone which would render the search a little useless :(

Comment: @K20GH instead of `OR` use `AND` or add :`LIKE '%".$splitKeyword[1]."%' LIMIT 1"`

Comment: unfortunately that messes up other results.  Will have to have a think.  The suggestions in autocomplete are formed into an array using 2 strings.  Will have to see if its possible to add the strings together for autocomplete, but split them for the searching...

Comment: if you use `LIMIT 0,1` keep `OR`

Comment: `'SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model FROM Device_tbl WHERE Manufacturer LIKE '%".$splitKeyword[0]."%' OR Model LIKE '%".$splitKeyword[1]."%' LIMIT 0,1"`   This gives a search of 'Motorola Xoom 2' a result of 'Motorola Xoom' for example

Comment: Excellent.  So this is working, only issue I have is that if I select a value and then delete it.  It doesn't reload everything (ie, it doesnt run the query with search_input set to *)